# SQLite: Why is foreign key constraint not working here?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Based on https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html I thought I would get a foreign key constraint error on the last row of this SQL when executed in SQLite but it just swallows it all and moves on. Why is that?

```
CREATE TABLE Person ( 
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE Child (
    parent_id INTEGER,
    child_id INTEGER,

    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES Person(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES Person(id)
);

INSERT INTO Person(name) 
       VALUES ('John Doe');
INSERT INTO Person(name) 
       VALUES ('Clara Doe');

INSERT INTO Child(parent_id, child_id) VALUES (45, 50);
```

Comment: You might need to run  `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` before your other queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first enable [foreign key enforcement](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys):

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
```

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

> 2. Enabling Foreign Key Support
>
> In order to use foreign key constraints in SQLite, the library must be
>   compiled with neither SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER
>   defined. If SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER is defined but SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY
>   is not, then SQLite behaves as it did prior to version 3.6.19
>   (2009-10-14) - foreign key definitions are parsed and may be queried
>   using PRAGMA foreign_key_list, but foreign key constraints are not
>   enforced. The PRAGMA foreign_keys command is a no-op in this
>   configuration. If OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY is defined, then foreign key
>   definitions cannot even be parsed (attempting to specify a foreign key
>   definition is a syntax error).

---

https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys

> PRAGMA foreign_keys;  PRAGMA foreign_keys = boolean;
>
> Query, set, or clear the enforcement of foreign key constraints.
>
> This pragma is a no-op within a transaction; foreign key constraint
>   enforcement may only be enabled or disabled when there is no pending
>   BEGIN or SAVEPOINT.
>
> Changing the foreign_keys setting affects the execution of all
>   statements prepared using the database connection, including those
>   prepared before the setting was changed. Any existing statements
>   prepared using the legacy sqlite3_prepare() interface may fail with an
>   SQLITE_SCHEMA error after the foreign_keys setting is changed.
>
> As of SQLite version 3.6.19, the default setting for foreign key
>   enforcement is OFF. However, that might change in a future release of
>   SQLite. The default setting for foreign key enforcement can be
>   specified at compile-time using the SQLITE_DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEYS
>   preprocessor macro. To minimize future problems, applications should
>   set the foreign key enforcement flag as required by the application
>   and not depend on the default setting.

---

```
sqlite> create table t1 (i int primary key);
sqlite> create table t2 (j references t1(i));
sqlite> insert into t2 values (1);
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
sqlite> insert into t2 values (1);
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Comment: Aha, no I just downloaded from https://sqlite.org/download.html. Where do I get a version that supports foreign keys then? :(

Comment: It seems the default version supports foreign keys, therefore @laalto answer is the correct one

Answer (score -1):

You can enforce foreign keys like below:

CREATE TABLE song(
  songid     INTEGER,
  songartist TEXT,
  songalbum TEXT,
  songname   TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY(songartist, songalbum) REFERENCES album(albumartist, albumname)
);